# Annotation Reflection for Method overrided

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

How to I can get the Annotation Object for method that was overriden.

```
/* I created a custom annotation named AclIgnore, 
   and I have the next following piece of code: */

public class abstract Parent{
    @AclIgnore
    public abstract String getName();

}

public class Children extends Parent{
    @Override
    public String getName(){
          return "theChildren";
   }
}

   /*I want the AclIgnore of Parent.getName() but the next code returns null */
/*method is getName of the instance*/
AclIgnore aclIgnore = method.getAnnotation(AclIgnore.class);
```

My Question is: Is it possible to get the `AclIgnore` annotation from the parent class when I have a `java.lang.reflect.Method` instance referring to the child's method?

Comment: Thanks @isnot2bad, I cannot found that question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`AnnotationUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html#findAnnotation(java.lang.reflect.Method,%20java.lang.Class)) class from Spring's core.

I think you'll get the annotation from parent's class as you need.

Comment: Great! I'm using Spring, I like this solution